# Celery queue fetch multiple messages at the same time

Tags: python, docker, rabbitmq, celery

I am working on a docker-based Celery-backed Python application in which one of the functionality is to trigger and send a text message given a number. The workflow is as follows:

1. User uploads a CSV with a set of entries to whom the text message should be sent
2. The cron job polls database every 60 seconds to fetch any new entries and adds them to the queue
3. If new entries are found, put them in the queue and trigger the text message

Currently, if I upload a CSV file with 3 entries, each text message action is triggered sequentially and not in parallel (default celery process bheaviour). For example, if the scheduler fetches a job from the queue every 10 seconds, the time taken to send 3 text messages will be 30 seconds.
**Since these jobs are independent of each other, I want to parallelize this such that all three text messages are sent at the same time.**

I have tried increasing the concurrency of the queue but assuming that each thread will be assigned one of the three messages but it does not work. I'm afraid there might be something that I am missing. **Is there some other configuration I need to add so that I can parallelize the jobs?**

Command to run celery queue

```
celery worker --app=worker.app --concurrency=5 --hostname=worker1@%h --loglevel=INFO-Q queue1 -Ofair
```

Celery configuration

```
app = Celery(
    'worker',
    broker=os.environ['CELERY_BROKER'],
    backend=os.environ['RABBITMQ_BACKEND'],
    include=['worker.tasks','worker.schedule']
)



app.conf.update(
    result_expires=3600,
    task_track_started=True,
    worker_prefetch_multiplier = 5
)

app.conf.beat_schedule = {
    "get-message": {
        "task": "worker.schedule.get_new_messages",
        "schedule": 10,
        'options': {'queue' : 'queue1'}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the groups in celery

> Groups are used to execute tasks in parallel. The group function takes in a list of signatures.

may be it can helpful for reference see below document

https://sayari3.com/articles/18-chains-groups-and-chords-in-celery/

Answer (score 0):

The best way to fix this problem is to fix the cron job.  In your cron job, instead of putting messages onto the queue, invoke your celery tasks.  The reason that messages are being processed sequentially currently depends on your implementation of `worker.schedule.get_new_messages`.  Most likely, that function is pulling more than one message off the queue at a time and the function processing those messages is doing one at a time.

The way to fix that is to make a task that sends one message and that's it.  For example:

```
@app.task('send_my_cool_message')
def send_sms_message(from_, to_, text):
    twilio_client = Client(settings.ACCOUNT_SID, settings.AUTH_TOKEN)
    twilio_client.messages.create(to=to_, from=from_, body=text)
```

Now in your cron job, you invoke a celery task for each message:

```
from celery import Celery
qs = Messages.objects.filter(created_at__gte=last_date_polled)
app = Celery(broker=settings.BROKER_URL, backend=settings.BACKEND_URL)
for message in qs:
    app.send_task('send_my_cool_message', kwargs={
        'from_': message.from_,
        'to_': message.to_,
        'text': message.text,
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same problem, only my application sends emails (instead of SMSs) via "post/json" to an email cloud web service. I was looking for a way to fetch a "X" number of tasks from RabbitMQ, process them in parallel using asyncio and then notify RabbitMQ about each task.

I found that you need to use greenlets or threads in order to instruct the celery worker to use an asynchronous way to process  tasks.

For example, in the initial post the command used to run the celery worker is:

```
celery worker --app=worker.app --concurrency=5 --hostname=worker1@%h --loglevel=INFO-Q queue1 -Ofair
```

You need to add the pool type parameter to the celery worker command (by default is prefork), for example:

```
celery worker --app=worker.app --pool=gevent --concurrency=5 --hostname=worker1@%h --loglevel=INFO-Q queue1 -Ofair
```

Note that you need to install "gevent" before being able to use it.

You can use "threads" also but I prefer "gevent" as I find it more efficient than using the OS thread subsystem.

More information can be found [here](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/userguide/concurrency/gevent.html) and [here](https://github.com/celery/celery/tree/main/examples/gevent).

I also found this [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xZ3kNS_G6vs) useful.